# QDom Remove Nodes

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dom, for-loop

I am trying to remove all the  nodes in my .xml. However, with the following codes, I could only remove the first and third  nodes, leaving the second node unable to be removed. I figured out that something is wrong with my for loop, but I am unable to determine what went wrong. It seemed to skip the removing of the second node.

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

malfunctions.xml:

```
<InjectedMalfunctions>
    <Malfunction>
        <Name>ABC1</Name>
        <Time>00:00:00</Time>
    </Malfunction>
    <Malfunction>
        <Name>ABC2</Name>
        <Time>01:00:00</Time>
    </Malfunction>
    <Malfunction>
        <Name>ABC3</Name>
        <Time>03:00:00</Time>
    </Malfunction>
</InjectedMalfunctions>
```

.cpp:

```
QFile inFile("C:/Test/malfunctions.xml");
inFile.open(IODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QDomDocument doc;
doc.setContent(&inFile);
inFile.close();

QDomNodeList nodes = doc.elementsbyTagName("Malfunction");
if(!nodes.isEmpty())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.count(); ++i)
    {
        QDomNode node = nodes.at(i);
        node.parentNode().removeChild(node);
    }
}

...
```

Results:

```
<InjectedMalfunctions>
    <Malfunction>
        <Name>ABC2</Name>
        <Time>01:00:00</Time>
    </Malfunction>
</InjectedMalfunctions>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`QDomNodeList` is a live list.
From the docs: [*The Document Object Model (DOM) requires these lists to be "live": whenever you change the underlying document, the contents of the list will get updated.*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtxml/qdomnodelist.html#details)

It skips the second node because you add 1 to your `i` variable, while at the same time you remove a node.

First loop:

```
nodes[Node1, Node2, Node3]
i = 0
remove nodes[0] (Node1)
```

Second loop:

```
nodes[Node2, Node3]
i = 1
remove nodes[1] (Node3)
```

After this your loop finishes. Try making a `while` loop that checks if the `nodes` list is empty, and remove the first node of the list:

```
while(!nodes.isEmpty())
{
   QDomNode node = nodes.at(0);
   node.parentNode().removeChild(node);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @thuga. Changing into a while loop that always remove the first node, worked. I didn't know it was a live list. Therefore, I kept missing the "second" node.